# TabLayout addOnTabSelectedListener is not working properly when I reopen the application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am working with TabLayout which shows tab icon red according to fragment selected in ViewPager. But I have been facing this problem for 2 weeks and I have been searching a lot to resolve this issue.

The problem is if I am at fragment user account and when I close the application, my user tab icon is selected. Now when I reopen the application fragment, my tab restaurant is loaded, but the user account tab icon is still selected, although restaurant tab icon should be selected.

I have attached screenshots for reference:

[user account image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c83dX.jpg)

[restaurant image after re open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOgVJ.jpg)

```
public class PagerMainActivity extends Fragment {

//This is our tablayout
public TabLayout tabLayout;
public static CustomViewPager viewPager;
AdapterPager adapter;
public int tabIconColor_Selected;
public int tabIconColor_DeSelected;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//    tabSelection();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pager, container, false);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager =  v.findViewById(R.id.pager);

   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.restaurent).setText("Restaurant"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.order).setText("Order"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.deals).setText("Deals"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.account).setText("Account"));



    viewPager =  v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new AdapterPager(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    adapter.getRegisteredFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
    viewPager.setAllowedSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection.none);

  //  setupTabIcons();
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tabSelected)
        {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabSelected.getPosition());
            if(UserAccountFragment.LOG_OUT_FLAG || UserAccountFragment.LOG_IN_FLAG){
                tabIconColor_Selected = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorDeal);
                tabSelected.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor_Selected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                UserAccountFragment.LOG_OUT_FLAG=false;
                UserAccountFragment.LOG_IN_FLAG=false;
            }

            tabIconColor_Selected = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorRed);
            tabSelected.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor_Selected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tabSelected){


            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabSelected.getPosition());
            tabIconColor_DeSelected = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorDeal);
            tabSelected.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor_DeSelected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tabSelected){

        }
    });



    return v;
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    }

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

}
```

Adapter

```
 SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
int mNumOfTabs;


    public AdapterPager(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int tabCount) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.mNumOfTabs=tabCount;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fm=null;

    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fm = new RestaurantsFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
             fm = new OrdersFragment();
          break;
        case 2:
            fm = new DealsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fm = new UserAccountFragment();
            break;

    }
    return fm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
    }

   /* @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
    // Do Nothing
    return saveState();
    }*/
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }

    }
```

Your views and solution will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you loading pages into your adapter?

Comment: I edit my post in which i share adapter where i am calling those views

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't create a new ``Fragment`` every time ``getItem()`` is called. When you say you "close" your app, what do you mean? Are you exiting with home button, back button..? I don't think your ``onCreateView()`` is being called again, so it is not being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually now i change my logic and i am giving custom .xml layout to tablayout. but now i am facing problem of image destroying....